# Thunderbird accounts

Tags: thunderbird

I may have to add a second account to my Thunderbird configuration.  I'm wondering what happens to my incoming mail?  Do I have separate sets of folder for each account or a do the two accounts share a single set of folders?

And if there are separate sets of folders for each account is there any way to combine or merge them?

This arises because I am forced to switch from one server to another.  After I switch, I will not be using the old server BUT I do wish to retain the old email.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of whoever may be interested.  It turns out the folders for the new account show up in the left hand pane along with the folders present before adding the new account. There is a heading for the folders in the two accounts and sub folders under those headings.  For example each account has a Inbox.  One can drag folders between the accounts BUT it appears it's a copy operation, not a move operation.  The source folder stays behind under its original account.